# IIS Media Server with C# client

Tags: iis, windows-media-server

I want to use IIS Media Server for audio streaming and implement C# program to playback the streaming data. The client program read the streaming data that downloaded in to memory and play the audio.
Anybody can help me to start of this work?

Comment: chatcja - Did you get anywhere with this?